# Graphic of a function in Latex document

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I would like to draw the graphic of a logarithmic functions, as

```
f(x)=\ln(2\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1})
f(x)=\ln(2\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+2})
```

along with their asymptote (which is in both cases `y=\ln2`).

I tried `\pgfplots` but I didn't manage to build the graphic.
How would you proceed?

Comment: Hi @Flavio, have you tried something? In that case a [`mwe`](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) would be useful for users to answer you question more precisely to your will.

Comment: Please show us what you have done with `pdfplots` so far. (otherwise the quesiton might be closed as a `please do this for me` type of question.

Comment: Do remember that you cannot use `\frac` in specifying a function to plot, it is a formatting macro, not something supported for calculations

Comment: I like to add that the functions in the question differ from the function originally asked by the OP. One user replaced the original function by the two new ones. It is true, that the OP most likely had a typo in the original function, though. In addition, ln(2) is not "the" asymptote ("their asymptote") of both functions, but ln(2) is an asymptote of both functions. Another asymptote is x=1 for one of them.

Comment: @Flavio Btw, which function f did you have in mind, originally? Can you edit your question, please?

Comment: @Flavio Please consider to accept one of the two answers to mark this question closed. If you have any more questions, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=1:5,
            samples=100,
            grid=both,
            no markers,
            axis equal]
        \addplot +[thick] {ln(2*(x*x+1)/(x*x-1))};
        \addplot +[thick, domain=0:5] {ln(2)};
        \addplot +[thick, dashed] coordinates {(1,0)(1,4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many options are self explaining, all the others can be found in the documentation, but the core you are interested in is the definition of `axis` environment and the usage of `\addplot` command.

- outer `tikzpicture` creates an enviroment where tikz/pgf commands are defined;
- `axis` is used to define the plot environment;
- option `domain=X_min:X_max` specify the input to the function from `X_min` to `X_max`
- `samples=N` give makes the plot smoother by using more point to sample curves;
- `grid` set the grid in the plot;
- `no markers` avoid plotting with points, printing only line;
- `axis equal` is self explaining: equalize axes.

Finally the `\addplot` command is used as follows:

- add options with `+[thick]` which appends options to presets, if you want to override precedent styles use  just e.g. `[thick, green]`;
- the argument in braces is the function to be plotted, as in `{ln(2*(x*x+1)/(x*x-1))}`.
- the last `\addplot` uses coordinate to plot the vertical asymptote at `x=1`.

## OUTPUT

[image: pgfplots]

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that there is a typo in your function *f* as the nominator equals the denominator, hence *f* is constant itself and *f* and its asymptote coincide. I randomly changed *f* below.

The second example follows section "22.5 Plotting a Function" of Ti*k*Z' manual on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,domain=-20:20, smooth]
        \addplot[samples=400]
            {ln(2*(x*x+1)/(x*x+2))}; 
        \addplot[]
            {ln(2)}; 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:5]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] 
        (-5,-1) grid (5,2);
    \draw[->] 
        (-5,0) -- (5.2,0) 
        node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] 
        (0,-1.2) -- (0,2.2) 
        node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[color=red] 
        plot (\x,{ln(2)}) 
        node[above] {$\ln2$};
    \draw[color=blue,samples=400,smooth] 
        plot (\x,{ln(2*(\x*\x+1)/(\x*\x+2))}) 
        node[below] {$f$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** requested by OP: I deleted the `grid` part and added the numbers more or less manually by the `\foreach` loop: It draws a line and adds the number automatically.
Observe: The second and third example do not need `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\xPlotMin}{-5}
\newcommand{\xPlotMax}{5}
\newcommand{\yPlotMin}{-1}
\newcommand{\yPlotMax}{2}
\newcommand{\axisSmallLength}{0.1}
%Be aware the simple implementation of the axis below might give silly results for unsuitable values. 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=\xPlotMin:\xPlotMax]
    \draw[->] 
        ({\xPlotMin-2*\axisSmallLength},0) -- ({\xPlotMax+2*\axisSmallLength},0) 
        node[right] {$x$};
    \foreach \x in {\xPlotMin,...,-1, 1,2,...,\xPlotMax}    
        {\draw (\x,\axisSmallLength) -- (\x,-\axisSmallLength) node[below] {$\x$};}

    \draw[->] 
        (0,{\yPlotMin-2*\axisSmallLength}) -- (0,{\yPlotMax+2*\axisSmallLength}) 
        node[above] {$y$};
    \foreach \y in {\yPlotMin,...,-1, 1,2,...,\yPlotMax}    
        {\draw (\axisSmallLength,\y) -- (-\axisSmallLength,\y) node[left] {$\y$};}

    \draw[color=red] 
        plot (\x,{ln(2)}) 
        node[above] {$\ln2$};
    \draw[color=blue,samples=400,smooth] 
        plot (\x,{ln(2*(\x*\x+1)/(\x*\x+2))}) 
        node[below] {$f$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both of you are amazing! Thanks so much! I've another question: how i can remove the grid and insert some numbers above or below the axis?

Comment: @Flavio I added a third example. If both of the answers are helpful. Please consider to upvote both.

Comment: Thank soooo much! I already tried to upvote the answers, but maybe I can do that only if I have 15 of reputation. How can i improve it?

Comment: @Flavio As far as I remember, there is a "tour" or so on this site. If you finish reading it, you get some more reputation and further information. You might find some information on your profile or on  https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour .